# The definition of sheaf $K^*/\mathcal{O}^*$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry, sheaf-theory

The sheaf $K^*/\mathcal{O}^*$ is defined as the sheafification of the cokernel from the inclusion $\mathcal{O}^*\to K^*$. For the  pre sheaf $(K^*/\mathcal{O}^*)^{pre}$, $(K^*/\mathcal{O}^*)^{pre}(U):=K^*(U)/\mathcal{O}^*(U)$, then any holomorphic function on $U$ is trivial on $(K^*/\mathcal{O}^*)^{pre}(U)$, but after sheafification a holomorphic function on $U$ $K^*/\mathcal{O}^*(U)$ may not be trivial since otherwise the effective divisors from $H^0(X,K^*/\mathcal{O}^*)$ are all the same, I wonder how to see after sheafification, it makes this difference?

Comment: I'd say $K^*(U)/O^*(U)$ is the group of principal divisors on $U$, on a non-compact Riemann surface it is a sheaf (every divisor is principal) and on a compact Riemann surface it is only a presheaf (only certain degree $0$ divisors are principal, $D = (0)$ is a principal divisor on $\Bbb{C}$ and $\Bbb{C}^*\cup \infty$ but not on $\Bbb{C} \cup \infty$)

Comment: On a compact Riemann surface is the sheafication the group of Cartier divisors, isomorphic to the sheaf $Div$ of all divisors  ?